# List details student, due date, percentage. i want to send mail after due date until percentage gets hundred % approved in sharepoint designer 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Sharepoint query to send mail until it gets hundred percentage

Comment: Please explain your question in a more concise and clarified manner.

Comment: We need more information to answer your question. Please edit  your post and add details as requested by the community. It will be  closed for now, but don't worry - once you have improved the question  flag a moderator and it can be reopened. See our [FAQ](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#questions) for general guidelines.

Comment: Please explain your question with more details if you think we know your default setting and pages you designed and your desired and ... please describe more to help you

Answer (score 1):

The scenario you describe is similar enough to this article for me to recommend it:
http://sharepointmagazine.net/articles/the-dog-ate-my-task-use-sharepoint-designer-to-email-daily-task-reminders

Create a SharePoint Designer workflow that fires whenever an item is created AND whenever an item is changed. In the initial step of the workflow, check if the percentage field value equals 100. If it doesn't, send an email and use a "Pause" activity that will effectively cause the workflow to run every 24 hours (or however often you need to send the emails). After the pause, update another field's value in the list (in the article, they increment a field called "EmailReminderCount," but it can be anything). This will kick off the workflow again, since you set it to run whenever an item is changed. The workflow will continue to run and send emails until the percentage equals 100.

Comment: Hi Danny,thanks a lot for your immediate reply. I will explain it in a simple manner. Say i have two columns called "due date" and "percentage". Mail should trigger every day after due date, until percentage gets 100%. If it is not possible in designer can you provide me the code(VS 2010).